# How to display telugu font?

Tags: android, fonts

I have use two tablets one is jellybean 7inch., tablet and other one is ice cream sandwich 8inch., tablet my problem is in jellybean tab my telugu font is working but ice cream sandwich telugu font not display properly.

Thank U advice

Answer (score 0):

Versions of android before Jellybean used the older version of HarfBuzz which didn't render Telugu and other Indic-like scripts as well as the new HarfBuzz.  There's not much you can do about this.